# Difference between Service and Systemctl

Tags: linux, service, command, systemctl

**systemctl** command which is mostly used to enable services to start at boot time.

**systemctl enable service_name**, and the service will automatically start at boot time.

What is the use of **service start service_name**

Comment: refer this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/903354/difference-between-systemctl-and-service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both commands are used to up and down services in GNU/Linux.

But, `service` command is using by sysvinit, and `systemctl` is using by systemd.

In systemd, `service` command exists yet, but only to legacy compatibility with old sysvinit scripts